# No desaparece el fragment anterior al pasar de un fragment a otro en Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Tengo una aplicación en [android-studio](/questions/tagged/android-studio) que tiene una barra de menú abajo, de uno de los fragments, quiero pasar a otro que yo he hecho, el problema es que se sigue viendo la lista del fragment anterior.

Este es mi `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{



  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
      // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
      // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
      AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
              R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
              .build();
      NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
      NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
      NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);


  }


}
```

el layout de Activity Main (activity_main)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
    />




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Este es el fragmento que sale primero, Home Fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements DBInterface, RecordListAdapter.MyViewHolder.onRecordListener {
    private User actual_user = User.getUser();
    //private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private JSONArray results;
    private RecordListAdapter.MyViewHolder.onRecordListener listener;

    private View root;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


        getList();
        if(results != null)
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return root;
    }



    public void getList(){
        //Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        try {
            params.put("email", actual_user.getEmail() );
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(params != null){
            DBAccess.getRecords(getContext(), this, params);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error" + "Ha ocurrido un error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Error" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("response","error" + error.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            if (response.has("type")) {
                if("RECORD".equals(response.getString("type"))){
                    Log.d("response","records list");
                    //Show all the records
                    int num = response.length();
                    //if(num > 1){
                        results = response.getJSONArray("Results");
                        /*for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject aux = results.getJSONObject(i);
                            Log.d("response","ID" + aux.get("ID"));
                        }*/

                    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)  getView().findViewById(R.id.list_Records_today);
                    //We create the adapter

                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
                    ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

                    // specify an adapter
                        mAdapter = new RecordListAdapter(results, this);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                        DividerItemDecoration divider = new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).getOrientation());
                        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(divider);

                        Log.d("response","fin");
                    //}
                    /*else{
                        //there is only one show the only one
                        Log.d("response","solo uno");
                    }*/

                }
                else{
                    //there is not records
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No registros",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            else{
                Log.d("response","error param");
                if (response.has("ERROR")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.getString("ERROR"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRecordItemClick(int position) {
        try {
            int id = getID(position);
            // Create fragment and give it an argument specifying the article it should show
            //RecordView newFragment = new RecordView(getID(position),getName(position),getDate(position),getTime(position));
            RecordView newFragment = new RecordView();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
            //transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, newFragment);
            transaction.replace(this.getId(), newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Su layout (fragment_home)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Fragment_home_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_Records_today"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Y al fragment que quiero pasar, al tocar uno de los items de la lista:

```
public class RecordView extends Fragment {

    private int ID;
    private String date, time,name;
    /*public RecordView(int ID,String name, String date,String time) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.name = name;
    }*/
    public RecordView(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_record_view, container, false);
        TextView name_item = root.findViewById(R.id.record_view_name);
        name_item.setText("HELLOUUUU");
        return root;
    }
}
```

Su layout (fragment_record_view)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RecordView">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/record_view_name"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd" />
</FrameLayout>
```

El resultado es que se ve a la vez la lista y el texto diciendo "Hellou". ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Muchas gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Hay algo muy importante que dese saber acerca de los `Fragments` y es que **solo se pueden reemplazar aquellos que se han agregado dinamicamnente usando código en un contenedor mediante `FragmentTransaction`**.

Por lo tanto primeramente tienes que agregar el Fragment y posteriormente este se puede reemplazar, ejemplo:

```
FragmentEjemplo fragment = new FragmentEjemplo ();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment, "nombreFragment");  
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

En tu caso ya estas definiendo un Fragment , por  esta razón este no se esta reemplazando:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navG
```

Comment: He hecho esto transaction.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, newFragment, "nombreFragment");
            transaction.commit();
            transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, newFragment); 
Pero sigue sin funcionar :(

Comment: Vale lo que pasaba es que con el al haber hecho la aplicación con la barra de navegación abajo, hay que navegar con el nav View.